# Not able to Pull from Docker Although image is present in docker hub

Tags: docker, docker-compose

There has one image and it is public in my dockerhub account
I have logged in from my console then try following command but not able to pull the image

```
rajarshi@rajarshi-X200CA:~$ sudo docker pull rajcybage/tomcat8_rajarshidd
Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository docker.io/rajcybage/tomcat8_rajarshidd
Tag latest not found in repository docker.io/rajcybage/tomcat8_rajarshidd
```

Any help would really appreciable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you search [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com) for `tomcat8_rajarshidd`, you can find its page, then click the [tags tab](https://hub.docker.com/r/rajcybage/tomcat8_rajarshidd/tags/) to view available tags.

At the time of this writing, the only available tag is `2`. As the error told you, there is no `latest` tag available.

So all you need to do is use a valid tag. There's only one you can use in this case:

```
docker pull rajcybage/tomcat8_rajarshidd:2
```

If this is your image, you can create a `latest` tag easily.

```
docker tag <image-id> rajcybage/tomcat8_rajarshidd:latest
docker push rajcybage/tomcat8_rajarshidd:latest
```

This would not push any new layers, as the layers are already present on Docker Hub, but it would attach the `latest` tag to this image.

Comment: Thank you @Dan Lowe